# Infowindow help on google maps api 3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, infowindow

Having similar problem as others have had on this website where it shows only the last marker's info window info in all markers. Can't seem to solve this with any of the solutions given. Also, the last one of my markers doesn't show an info window at all.

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="data2.json"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/markerclusterer.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load('maps', '3', {
    other_params: 'sensor=false'
  });
  google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);

  function initialize() {

var center = new google.maps.LatLng(55.4419, -4.1419);

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 5,
      center: center,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });


var markers = [];
for (var i = 0, dataPhoto; dataPhoto = data.markers[i]; i++) {
      var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(dataPhoto.latitude,dataPhoto.longitude);
      var theTitle = dataPhoto.address;
      var contentString = '<div align="left"><img src="logo.gif" alt="" width="242" height="71" /><br /><br /><p style="color:#000000;">' + data.markers[i].address + '<br />' + dataPhoto.telephone + '</p></div>';



      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString,
        });



    var thisIcon = 'markers/image.png';


                for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {infowindow.open(map,this);});
      } 


      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        clickable: true,
        title: theTitle,
        icon: thisIcon,
      });

      markers.push(marker);
    }
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);


  }


</script>
```

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have not tested this but it should work - also please have a look at : http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/events.html#EventClosures

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="data2.json">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/markerclusterer.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('maps', '3', {
        other_params: 'sensor=false'
    });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);

    function initialize(){

        var center = new google.maps.LatLng(55.4419, -4.1419);

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 5,
            center: center,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });


        var markers = [];
        for (var i = 0, dataPhoto; dataPhoto = data.markers[i]; i++) {
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(dataPhoto.latitude, dataPhoto.longitude);
            var theTitle = dataPhoto.address;
            var contentString = '<div align="left"><img src="logo.gif" alt="" width="242" height="71" /><br /><br /><p style="color:#000000;">' + data.markers[i].address + '<br />' + dataPhoto.telephone + '</p></div>';
            var thisIcon = 'markers/image.png';
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng,
                clickable: true,
                title: theTitle,
                icon: thisIcon,
            });

            attachIWindow(contentString, marker);


            markers.push(marker);
        }
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);


    }

    function attachIWindow(content, marker){


        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: content,

        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you!! Just had to move where you define the function attachIWindow in your solution up above where it is called, then it works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

We can make use of **closures** to solve this problem

Use the below code snippet to add **info window** to **marker**

```
function AddInfoWidnow(marker,message)
{
     var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: message });

     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

     infowindow.open(marker.get('map'), marker);

    }); 

}
```

To see a working sample refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22095008/730807)

Answer (score 0):

If I get this right then please take a look at closures and try to understand them properly.Then javascript magic will happen!