# Trying to display InfoWindow data from JSON on multiple markers

Tags: google-maps

I have multiple markers loading from a JSON file into google maps v3 api.  However it is only loading the last JSON entry into the map infoWindow on the last marker.  The other markers do not show any info window when clicked.

I have found the below related posts but still cannot seem to get this to work.

[..3979486/infowindow-help-on-google-maps-api-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979486/infowindow-help-on-google-maps-api-3)

[..2357323/trying-to-bind-multiple-infowindows-to-multiple-markers-on-a-google-map-and-faili](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357323/trying-to-bind-multiple-infowindows-to-multiple-markers-on-a-google-map-and-faili)

I am guessing it has something to do with location of the addListener?

Here is what I got:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="markerclusterer.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(39.632906,-106.524591);
  var myOptions = {
     zoom: 8,
     center: myLatlng,
     mapTypeControl: true,
     mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
     navigationControl: true,
     navigationControlOptions: {style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL},
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
     };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapdiv"), myOptions);

    var url = "eventdata.json";
      $.getJSON(url,
        function(data){ 
              $.each(data.markers, function(i,markers){

                  var mylati = data.markers[i].lati;
                  var mylong = data.markers[i].long;
                  var mytitle = data.markers[i].title;
                  var myaddress = data.markers[i].address;
                  var myhtml = data.markers[i].html;

    var mycontent = "<div class='infowin'><h3>" + mytitle + "</h3>" + "<h4>"
    + myaddress + "</h4>" + myhtml + "</div>";

    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(mylati),parseFloat(mylong));



                <!--Load Event Markers-->
                    var markers = [];
                    for (var i = 0, dataMarkers; dataMarkers = data.markers[i]; i++) {
                      var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(dataMarkers.lat, dataMarkers.lng);
                      var theTitle = dataMarkers.title;
                      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: latLng,
                        clickable: true,
                        title: theTitle,
                      });
                      markers.push(marker);
                    }

                        var markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
                          maxZoom: 15,
                          gridSize: 30,
                        });

                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: mycontent
                    });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });




       });
    });

    }

</script>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at [this](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#event_closure_v3) and try to understand closures

Answer (score 0):

Read through closures and figured this out...

```
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), options);


                var markers = [];
                for (var i = 0, dataMarkers; dataMarkers = data.markers[i]; i++) {
                  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(dataMarkers.lat, dataMarkers.lng);
                  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latLng,
                    title: dataMarkers.title,
                    date: dataMarkers.date,
                    time: dataMarkers.time,
                    desc: dataMarkers.desc,
                    img: dataMarkers.img,
                    add: dataMarkers.address,
                    cat: dataMarkers.cat,
                    map: map
                  });


                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: " "
                      });
                      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                        infowindow.setContent('<div id="mapCont"><img class="mapImg" src="'+this.img+'"/>' +
                                              '<div class="mapTitle">'+this.title+'</div>' + 
                                              '<div class="mapHead">Date: <div class="mapInfo">'+this.date+'</div>' +
                                              '<div class="mapHead">Time: <div class="mapInfo">'+this.time+'</div>' +
                                              '<p>'+this.desc+'</p></div>');
                        infowindow.open(map, this);
                      });

                  markers.push(marker);
                }


            var markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
              maxZoom: 15,
              gridSize: 50
            });
```

}